# JSON response Issue for Jira Rest Client

Tags: java, json, jira-rest-api

When I use the following method :

```
public String getProjectList() {
    projNames = new ArrayList<>();
    projNames.add("Project1");
    projNames.add("Project2");
    projNames.add("Project3");
    return new Gson().toJson(projNames);
```

in the following code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('DBDropDown', function(resp) { // on sucess
            var $select = $('#someselect');
            $select.find('option').remove();
            $select.prepend("<option value='Select Project'></option>").val('');
            $.each(resp, function(key, value) { // Iterate over the JSON object.
                $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select); // Create HTML <option> element, set its value with currently iterated key and its text content with currently iterated item and finally append it to the <select>.
            });
        }).fail(function() { // on failure
            alert("Request failed.");
        });
    });
```

and my JSP call is :

```
response.getWriter().write(MusicDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getProjectList()
```

I am able to get the dropdown menu. But when I use this method in place of getProjectList I dont get a response when I check chrome developer tools and debug.

```
public String Names() throws URISyntaxException{
    names = new ArrayList<>();
    URI uri = new URI("https://jira.xxxxx.com");
    JiraRestClientFactory jrcf = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
    JiraRestClient jrc = jrcf.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, "xxx", "xxxx");

    Iterable<BasicProject> allproject = jrc.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim();
    for(BasicProject project : allproject){
        names.add(project.getName());
    }

    return new Gson().toJson(names);
}
```

I am not getting any response and console throws ClassDefNotFound Exception when I already have all the classes needed. Help me if you have gone through this type of issue.

Thanks